# Why is oauth2client throwing a urlencode error in my dev environment?

Tags: python

I am using google-api-python-client to site-wide delegate auth for a calendar building program I am writing.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import httplib2
import json

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open('privatekey.pem', 'rb') as f:
    key = f.read()

with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

service_account_name = config['account_email'] 
calendarId = config['calendarId']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    service_account_name, key,
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)
```

I do not have any issue running this on my production server, however on my dev (personal laptop) it is throwing a I do not have any issue running this on my production server, however on my dev (personal laptop) is throwing an error on urlencode. From my understanding `urllib.parse.urlencode` is the python 3 path? Why is my dev calling this ?

```
File "cal.py", line 27, in <module>
service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 196, in build
resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 534, in new_request
self._refresh(request_orig)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 748, in _refresh
self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 772, in _do_refresh_request
body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1381, in _generate_refresh_request_body
body = urllib.parse.urlencode({
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlencode'
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Weirdly, if I install the dependencies into the current directory, I works. It only fails when I install them to my system directory.